# How to increment id by same count for all rows inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure that inserts three rows into our database calculating daily averages. I want to assign a batch count [Eg: 1, 2, 3 etc..] and unable to find a way to do that.

Currently I have set the batchid column to be auto increment, but it increases the batch id for each row. I would like that when the first batch of inserts go in, it has the 1 batch id, and the next time it inserts it gets plus 1 count

```
    insert into sales
    select site, avg(sales), avg(income), getdate() from product sales
```

Currently it goes in as

```
site| sales| income| [current_date]      |      batch_id
1908| 45   | 2100  | 2023-07-10 11:00:00 |    1
2506| 23   | 1200  | 2023-07-10 11:00:00 |    2
3625| 25   | 1350  | 2023-07-10 11:00:00 |    3
```

But I want it to go in as

```
site| sales| income| [current_date]      | batch_id
1908| 45   | 2100  | 2023-07-10 11:00:00 |    1
2506| 23   | 1200  | 2023-07-10 11:00:00 |    1
3625| 25   | 1350  | 2023-07-10 11:00:00 |    1

next insert:
site| sales| income [current_date]       batch_id
1908| 45   | 2100   2023-07-10 11:00:00     1
2506| 23   | 1200   2023-07-10 11:00:00     1
3625| 25   | 1350   2023-07-10 11:00:00     1
1908| 24   | 1200   2023-07-11 11:00:00     2
2506| 37   | 1800   2023-07-11 11:00:00     2
3625| 35   | 1650   2023-07-11 11:00:00     2
```

Comment: Use a `SEQUENCE` not an `IDENTITY`, obtain the next value of the `SEQUENCE` first, and then `INSERT` that.

Comment: You could also not store a batch_id at all and just compute it when you need it using a view.

Answer (score 0):

I offer my solution and i hope it helps.

First I create the sequence in this way:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE secventa
        AS INT
        START WITH 1
        INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Then I create the trigger which will populate column batch_id after each batch of inserting

```
CREATE or alter TRIGGER increment_secventa
ON sales
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @BatchId INT;

    SET @BatchId = NEXT VALUE FOR secventa;

    UPDATE sales
    SET batch_id = @BatchId
    FROM inserted
    WHERE sales.site = inserted.site
    AND sales.sales = inserted.sales
    AND sales.income = inserted.income
    AND sales.data = inserted.data
    AND sales.batch_id IS NULL;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no built in option for this, you need to select max batch in same site and increment it by one like this:

```
insert into sales(site, sales, income, [current_date], batch_id
select site, avg(sales), avg(income), getdate(), (select (MAX(sa.batch_id) + 1) from sales AS sa where sa.site = site ) AS newBatchId from product sales
```

Answer (score -3):

```
DECLARE @sequenceid INT
SET @sequenceid =  (CONVERT(INT,(SELECT current_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'BatchSequence'))+ 1)

insert into sales
select site, avg(sales), avg(income), getdate(), @sequenceid from product sales
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea. It creates a race condition and has tons of concurrency issues.